# Shorten nested lambda

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to map a list of tasks to `List<Callable<Tasks>>`:

```
List<Callable<Tasks>> callableTasks = tasks.stream().map(t ->
        {
            // how to return callable directly and omitting curly braces?
            Callable<Task> task = () -> run(t);
            return task;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I shorten the above expression to return the callable directly?

Comment: sure, it returns callables..

Comment: Please read the question: How can I shorten above expression to return the callable *directly*?

Comment: Something like `tasks.stream().map(t -> () -> run(t)).collect(Collectors.toList());`  is not right..what is the right syntax for that?

Comment: Does `.map(t -> (Callable<Task>)() -> run(t))` work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use static methods from [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)  class, for example `Executors.callable`:

```
tasks.stream().map(t -> callable(() -> run(t))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice solution! I did it shorter with `tasks.stream().map(t->()->run(t);).collect(Collectors.toList())` but the syntax is little weird in this case. So I use your solution. Thanks!

Comment: `Executors.callable(…)` returns a `Callable<Object>` which will always evaluate to `null`, rather than a `Callable<Task>` that evaluates to the result of the `run(t)` method.

Comment: @nimo23 your `.map(t->()->run(t);)` is not valid syntax at all and it doesn’t solve the actual problem. You can always do shorter when you never really try the result.

Comment: @Holger yes, right. I put that code into eclipse IDE and it did not show any warnings or errors even if it is not the right syntax. But `.map(t->()->run(t);)` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the lambda expression `() -> run(t)` requires a *target type*.

In a construct like

```
List<Callable<Tasks>> callableTasks = tasks.stream()
    .map(…).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The assignment to `List<Callable<Tasks>> callableTasks` provides a target type to the `collect` method invocation, but can’t propagate it to the preceding `map` invocation (a general limitation of Java’s current type inference).

By splitting the mapping function into an assignment and a `return` statement, you are providing a target type. Likewise, you could provide target type by casting, e.g. `.map(t -> (Callable<Task>)() -> run(t))` or by providing an explicit type for the generic method `map`, e.g. `.<Callable<Task>>map(t -> () -> run(t))`.

The latter solution leads to

```
List<Callable<Task>> callableTasks = tasks.stream()
    .<Callable<Task>>map(t -> () -> run(t)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the `Task` instance returned by `run(t)` is the same as passed to it as argument, you can use `Executors.callable` like:

```
List<Callable<Task>> callableTasks = tasks.stream()
    .map(t -> Executors.callable(() -> run(t), t)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note the `Executors.callable` encapsulates a `Runnable`, which provides no return value. So the constructed `Callable` will evaluate to the result specified to `Executors.callable` as second argument or to `null` if you use the one argument version.